# How to submit multipart/form-data from react to express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, axios

I'm trying to submit a form with an *Image* & *Name* of Category. But in my ExpressJS (backend) I'm unable to fetch the data. In express I'm using `express-fileupload` package. Below is my code, please help me to come out from this problem.

**Front End (React - CategoryForm.js)**

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { Component } from "react";

class CategoryForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { name: '', file: '', fileName: '' };

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onChangeImageHandler = this.onChangeImageHandler.bind(this);
        this.onCreate = this.onCreate.bind(this);
    }

    /** Methods */
    onChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    onChangeImageHandler = e => this.setState({ fileName: e.target.files[0].name, file: e.target.files[0] });
    onCreate = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('name', this.state.name);
        formData.append('file', this.state.file);

        const url = 'http://localhost:4000/api/v2/categories';
        const token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVkZTc3MDM0NTgxM2QyN2NmZDExMWE3ZSIsImVtYWlsIjoiaGFyc2hhQHNrcmVlbS5pbyIsImlhdCI6MTU3NTQ0ODc1OSwiZXhwIjoxNTc2MzEyNzU5fQ.7wxCmPhkzb0aaB4q9PBKmHAj1Klw1NQmp1nBI3NsRRI';

        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                ContentType: 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            body: formData
        })
        .then(res => this.setState({ name: '', file: '', fileName: '' }))
        .catch(err => console.log('Error - ', err));
    }

    /** Rendering the Template */
    render() {

        const { name, fileName } = this.state;

        return (
                <form onSubmit={this.onCreate}>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="New Category Name" />
                    <input type="file" name="file" onChange={this.onChangeImageHandler} />
                    <button type="submit">Add Category</button>
                </form>
        )
    }
}

export default CategoryForm;
```

**Back End (ExpressJS : server.js)**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");

app.use(fileUpload());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/api/v2/categories',
        (req, res, next) => { console.log(req.body); },
        require("./categoryRoute"));
```

In `req.body` I'm getting { }. Please tell me **How can send Image with Text data to express**.

**Note** : If I'm passing only data (Not Image) from react, let say `data: {name: 'Shivam'}` then I'm getting it in backend.

Answer (score 1):

**React**:
convert your media file to **base64** string.

**Express Js:**
In express convert **base64** to image(img,pdf,xlxs,etc...)

```
    var base64Data = req.body.file_data // base64 string
    var file_name='123.png';
    var file_dir = "assets/client_folios/"
    var fs = require("fs");
    if (!fs.existsSync('assets/')){
      fs.mkdirSync('assets/');
    }
    if (!fs.existsSync(file_dir)){
       fs.mkdirSync(file_dir);
    }
    var file_path="assets/client_folios/"+file_name

     var file_path="assets/client_folios/"+file_name
    fs.writeFile(file_path, base64Data, 'base64',async function(err) {

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the code. I'll try to implement in my project. I will get back to you if I face any difficulties.